# Google Maps API v3 - Buttons and TextBoxes inside InfoWindow?

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the new maps v3 API from [gwt-google-apis](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/detail?name=gwt-maps-3.8.0-pre1.zip&can=2&q=).

Is it possible to capture events from GWT widgets that are inside InfoWindow? Am I missing something?

Tried code above (button.addClickHandler) and it doesn't show the alert:

```
    Marker m = Marker.create();
    m.setIcon(MarkerImage.create(icone));
    m.setPosition(LatLng.create(posicao.lat(), posicao.lng()));
    m.setMap(map);

    m.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            InfoWindow info = InfoWindow.create();

            Button button = new Button("Desativar");
            button.addClickHandler(new com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    Window.alert("click");

                }
            });

            final HTMLPanel html = new HTMLPanel(("<div id='button'></div>"));
            html.add(button, "button");

            info.setContent(html.getElement());
            info.setPosition(posicao);
            info.open(map);

        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to build a wrapper over InfoWindow to make it work.

```
public class NXInfoWindow {

    static class FakePanel extends ComplexPanel {
        public FakePanel(Widget w) {
            w.removeFromParent();
            getChildren().add(w);
            adopt(w);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAttached() {
            return true;
        }

        public void detachWidget() {
            this.remove(0);
        }
    }

    private InfoWindow info;

    private IsWidget widgetContent = null;

    private Long id;

    FakePanel widgetAttacher;

    public static NXInfoWindow create(Long id){
        NXInfoWindow myInfo = new NXInfoWindow();
        myInfo.info = InfoWindow.create(); 
        myInfo.id = id;
        return myInfo;
    };

    private void detachWidget() {
        if (this.widgetAttacher != null) {
            this.widgetAttacher.detachWidget();
            this.widgetAttacher = null;
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        info.close();
        detachWidget();
    }

    public void setPosition(LatLng posicao) {
        info.setPosition(posicao);
    }

    public void open(GoogleMap map) {
        info.open(map);
    }

    public void setContent(Widget value) {
        this.widgetContent = value;
        info.setContent(value.getElement());

        if (this.widgetAttacher == null) {
            addListener(info, "closeclick", new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    detachWidget();
                }
            });
            this.widgetAttacher = new FakePanel(value);
        } else if (this.widgetAttacher.getWidget(0) != value) {
            this.widgetAttacher.detachWidget();
            this.widgetAttacher = new FakePanel(value);
        }
    }

    private void setContent(Element element) {
        this.setContent(element);
    }

    public IsWidget getContentWidget() {
        return widgetContent;
    }

    public final native void addListener(JavaScriptObject jso, String whichEvent, Runnable handler)
    /*-{
        var that = jso;
        $wnd.google.maps.event.addListener(jso, whichEvent, function() {
          handler.@java.lang.Runnable::run()();
        });
      }-*/;
}
```

Comment: `setContent(Element element)` calls itself. Also you can use as close event handler the code: `info.addCloseClickListener(new CloseClickHandler() { @Override public void handle() { detachWidget(); }});` and remove the native method.

Comment: Make the default constructor private too, it will prevent users from calling it (it should be forbidden as your code does not support it).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is result of a broken hierarchy between the widgets, the normal way to do it is by attach / detach widget. You do it by setting of the widget's element. This is also matter of Google Maps API.

This can be resolved by using fake panel which will be part of the `InfoWindow`, so when you make `setContent(Widget widget)` the fake panel will be updated and the element of the widget will be set to the content (as previous).

Please take a look at this class:

```
public class MyInfoWindow extends InfoWindow {

  static class FakePanel extends ComplexPanel {
    public FakePanel(Widget w) {
      w.removeFromParent();
      getChildren().add(w);
      adopt(w);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAttached() {
      return true;
    }

    public void detachWidget() {
      this.remove(0);
    }
  }

  private IsWidget widgetContent = null;

  FakePanel widgetAttacher;

  public MyInfoWindow() {
    super(InfoWindowImpl.impl.construct());
  }

  private void detachWidget() {
    if (this.widgetAttacher != null) {
      this.widgetAttacher.detachWidget();
      this.widgetAttacher = null;
    }
  }

  public void close() {
    super.close();
    detachWidget();
  }

  public void setContent(String content) {
    this.widgetContent = null;
    this.detachWidget();
    super.setContent(content);
  }

  /** */
  public void setContent(Widget value) {
    this.widgetContent = value;
    setContent(value.getElement());

    if (this.widgetAttacher == null) {
      addListener(getJso(), "closeclick", new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          detachWidget();
        }
      });
      this.widgetAttacher = new FakePanel(value);
    } else if (this.widgetAttacher.getWidget(0) != value) {
      this.widgetAttacher.detachWidget();
      this.widgetAttacher = new FakePanel(value);
    }
  }

  private void setContent(Element element) {
    InfoWindowImpl.impl.setContent(getJso(), element);
  }

  public IsWidget getContentWidget() {
    return widgetContent;
  }

  public final native void addListener(JavaScriptObject jso, String whichEvent, Runnable handler)
  /*-{
    var that = jso;
    $wnd.google.maps.event.addListener(jso, whichEvent, function() {
      handler.@java.lang.Runnable::run()();
    });
  }-*/;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're talking about the new Mapsv3 bindings (link below)?? I couldn't find InfoWindowImpl on my classpath http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/detail?name=gwt-maps-3.8.0-pre1.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: I use v3, but not the same wrapper for GWT, I use following lib: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/   Even if you do not have InfoWindowImpl class, you can implement the native methods. See the source here: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/source/browse/src/com/google/gwt/maps/client/base/impl/InfoWindowImpl.java

Comment: Thanks Goran. Your code helped me to find a solution for maps v3 on gwt-google-apis (other answer).