# GWT - button inside v3 google maps infowindow

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, gwt2, infowindow

I am trying to figure out how to propagate events for components inside google maps InfoWindow.
I create anchor or a button and want to handle click event on any of those.

I have found solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528637/google-maps-api-v3-buttons-and-textboxes-inside-infowindow)
and
[here](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-web-toolkit@googlegroups.com/msg82149.html)

but those both are using google maps wrappers for gwt.
I would like to avoid those libraries.

QUESTION:

Do you know any way how can I propagate those events from info window to some GWT panel which wraps google maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on code found here:
http://gwt-maps3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/com/googlecode/maps3/client/

I have created this class that solves problem with using no external library (you have to take Only InfoWindowJSO source from link given)
And then instead passing InnerHtml as string to setContent... you just pass Widget element.

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ComplexPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class InfoWindow
{
        static class FakePanel extends ComplexPanel
        {
                public FakePanel(Widget w)
                {
                        w.removeFromParent();
                        getChildren().add(w);
                        adopt(w);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isAttached()
                {
                        return true;
                }

                public void detachWidget()
                {
                        this.remove(0);
                }
        }

        /** */
        InfoWindowJSO jso;

        /** If we have a widget, this will exist so we can detach later */
        FakePanel widgetAttacher;

        /** Keep track of this so we can get it again later */
        Widget widgetContent;

        /** */
        public InfoWindow()
        {
                this.jso = InfoWindowJSO.newInstance();
        }

        /** */
        public InfoWindow(InfoWindowOptions opts)
        {
                this.jso = InfoWindowJSO.newInstance(opts);
        }

        /** Detaches the handler and closes */
        public void close()
        {
                this.detachWidget();
                this.jso.close();
        }

        /** Detaches the content widget, if it exists */
        private void detachWidget()
        {
                if (this.widgetAttacher != null)
                {
                        this.widgetAttacher.detachWidget();
                        this.widgetAttacher = null;
                }
        }

        /** */
        public void open(JavaScriptObject map)
        {
                this.jso.open(map);
        }

        public void open(JavaScriptObject map, JavaScriptObject marker)
        {
                this.jso.open(map, marker);
        }

        /** */
        public void setOptions(InfoWindowOptions value)
        {
                this.jso.setOptions(value);
        }

        /** */
        public void setContent(String value)
        {
                this.widgetContent = null;
                this.detachWidget();
                this.jso.setContent(value);
        }

        /** */
        public void setContent(Element value)
        {
                this.widgetContent = null;
                this.detachWidget();
                this.jso.setContent(value);
        }

        /** */
        public void setContent(Widget value)
        {
                this.widgetContent = value;
                this.detachWidget();
                this.jso.setContent(value.getElement());

                if (this.widgetAttacher == null)
                {
                        // Add a hook for the close button click
                        this.jso.addListener("closeclick", new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                        detachWidget();
                                }
                        });
                        this.widgetAttacher = new FakePanel(value);
                }
                else if (this.widgetAttacher.getWidget(0) != value)
                {
                        this.widgetAttacher.detachWidget();
                        this.widgetAttacher = new FakePanel(value);
                }
        }

        /** @return the widget, if a widget was set */
        public Widget getContentWidget()
        {
                return this.widgetContent;
        }

        /** */
        public JavaScriptObject getPosition()
        {
                return this.jso.getPosition();
        }

        /** */
        public void setPosition(JavaScriptObject value)
        {
                this.jso.setPosition(value);
        }

        /** */
        public int getZIndex()
        {
                return this.jso.getZIndex();
        }

        /** */
        public void setZIndex(int value)
        {
                this.jso.setZIndex(value);
        }

        /** */
        public void addListener(String whichEvent, Runnable handler)
        {
                this.jso.addListener(whichEvent, handler);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A. Browser events bubble all the way to the top of the DOM tree. You can attach your click handlers to a widget that is parent to both the maps InfoWindow and your widget. Then, when a user clicks on your button, you need to check for the source of event to make sure it came from your button.

```
public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {    
    Element e = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
    // check if e is your button
}
```

B. You can create a regular GWT button, attach a ClickHandler to it. Do not put it inside the InfoWindow: place it on top it using absolute positioning and a higher z-index.

Answer (score 2):

I use the static value nextAnchorId to uniquely generate IDs for each InfoWindow, and when the InfoWindow is ready (usually when you call infoWindow.open(map);), I get the anchor by element ID and add my click handler to it. This is kind of what Manolo is doing, but this implementation doesn't require gwtquery, which means that I can run my code in Super Dev Mode.

```
private static int nextAnchorId = 1;

public InfoWindow makeInfo() {
    InfoWindowOptions infoWindowOptions = InfoWindowOptions.create();
    FlowPanel infoContentWidget = new FlowPanel();
    final String theAnchorId_str = "theAnchor" + nextAnchorId;
    HTML theAnchor = new HTML("<a id=\"" + theAnchorId_str + "\">Click me!</a>");
    infoContentWidget.add(theAnchor);
    infoWindowOptions.setContent(infoContentWidget.getElement());
    InfoWindow infoWindow = InfoWindow.create(infoWindowOptions);

    infoWindow.addDomReadyListenerOnce(new InfoWindow.DomReadyHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle() {
            com.google.gwt.user.client.Element muffinButton = (com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) Document.get().getElementById(theAnchorId_str);
            DOM.sinkEvents(muffinButton, Event.ONCLICK);
            DOM.setEventListener(muffinButton, new EventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
                  Window.alert("You clicked on the anchor!");
                  // This is where your click handling for the link goes.
                }
            });
        }
    });

    nextAnchorId++;
    return infoWindow
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to use gwtquery:

Identify the anchor in the map you want to add the click handler and define a css selector for that (for instance id=my_link)

Use gquery to locate it and to add the event.

```
$('#my_link').click(new Function() {
   public boolean f(Event e) {
     [...]
     return false; //false means stop propagation and prevent default
   }
});
```

Note that gwtquery is not a wrapper of jquery but an entire gwt implementation of its api, so including it in your project will not overload it, and the compiler will pick up just the stuff you use.